# counter on each images in view

Tags: views, 7, nodes

I have a view that display 8 images(which links to their particular node) uploaded by the all users, now i want to display a counter which counts total number of times that image or that image link have been visited/viewed.

Please help me.

I think ..Its like if you on the left of this Question answer section on this site they have mentioned three things
1.Asked Today
2.Viewed 4 times(or total no. of times viewed )
3.etc

my requirement is second.
Thanks

Comment: I got the answer by using view content statistics, no need of any module..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Node view count](https://drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) module would be suitable, especially as it integrates with views.